# How to join array values in XQuery?

Tags: arrays, xquery

I have an array in XQuery:

```
let $arr := array {"Foo", "Bar"}
```

I want to join the array values with the separator `;` so that I get the string

```
"Foo;Bar"
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `$arr?*` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-postfix-lookup) to get a sequence of items in the array and then use `string-join` as you already found: `string-join($arr?*, ';')`.

For nested arrays you might want to use `array:flatten` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-array-flatten.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way by turning the array into a sequence first with [`fn:data`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_data.html), and then using [`fn:string-join`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_string-join.html) on this sequence:

`string-join(data($arr), ";")`